# Google Maps Javascript API v3 - Maps Are not Loading

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having quite a bit of difficulty with the implementation of the Google Maps Javascript API on my website. I followed Google's documentation when I integrated the map and had it appear and resize appropriately.

Now when I implemented this, it ran perfectly when viewing my local html files in browser. But the moment I uploaded my .js and .html files to my Amazon S3 website, the maps only work intermittently.

Sometimes the maps show up, sometimes I have to refresh 2-3 times to see the map. Some days it just never shows up.

Here are some sample pages on my site (all the way at the bottom)
http://plangaroo.com/pointreyes.html
http://plangaroo.com/srilanka-bentota1.html

Help?

Comment: Where is the callback function defined you specified in script src path.

Comment: Dont load file that contain initLoad function asynchronously, remove **async defer**  to `<script src="js/gmap-srilanka-bentota1.js"></script>`

Comment: should I also remove async defer for the javascript API initialization step?

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=$$$$&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

Comment: No, just load your script without async defer.

Comment: omg. Magic. This really worked!!! Do you mind explaining to me why this worked (and wasn't a problem when loading the site locally)?

Comment: And @jaguwalapratik how do I select your answer?

Comment: As you host your application locally all your assets(js, css) are local, so it is loaded very quickly, it doesn't make any difference weather you load js in async or sync manner from local environment, that's why you have not faced an issue in local environment. Where as in live environment it depends on the hosted environment  how fast they serve the resources. That is why you see that map works intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `async defer` from `<script src="js/gmap-pointreyes.js" async defer></script>`